# Best way to search for vector values in a file

Tags: c++, csv, vector

for a project, I'm trying to use my randomly generated vector to compare to a given CSV file full of int data. My vector is 6 random numbers, I need to read my csv files, and check if those numbers within my vector exist in all of the files.

What is the best way to access my vector one by one, and compare to all files? my code below worked fine when I originally used an array to store the random numbers but after changing over to a vector, it doesnt seem to work.

I'm very new to C++ for context

```
int csv_reader() {
string line; 
vector<int> numbers;
int filecontents = 0;

num_gen(numbers);
    
std::string path_to_dir = "example/directory/to/csv's";

for( const auto & entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator( path_to_dir )) {
    if (entry.path().extension().string() != ".csv") continue;
    ifstream file(entry.path());

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(file, line))
        {
            file >> filecontents;

            for(int i = 0; i > numbers.size(); i++)
            {
            if(filecontents == numbers.at(i))
            cout << "success";
            else
            cout << "doesnt exist";    
            }
```

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i > numbers.size(); i++)` is a typo. You want the loop to continue as long as `i < numbers.size()` not `>`

Comment: Recommendation: Start with a simple program that will read one file and print out all of the numbers in it one by one. When you get that working you can move on to comparing the number read against the random numbers and then onto reading multiple files. If you try to do all three at once, you'll have to debug all three at once.

Comment: So, you want to verify that all 6 random numbers are present anywhere in all the files?

Comment: yes @TedLyngmo that's correct. I need to access the vector in order and compare against my files anywhere within those files.

Comment: @SamHughes That seems a bit backwards. Open one file at a time and check if it contains all 6 numbers. If you while reading a file have found all 6, you can close that file and get on with the next one. If you get to the end of a file when reading it (and you haven't found all 6), you can abort the whole thing. The result is then `false`.

Comment: is this supposed to be something about indexing? otherwise as others said open one-by-one would probably be the most straightforward way.